# ActionBarCompat in FragmentActivty

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I am getting error
"The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type MainActivity"

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();


    //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);


    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
.
.
.
}
```

Please help me out. Does setHomeButtonEnabled() support?

Which is better ActionBarCompat or ActionBarSherlock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When application is using `getSupportActionBar()` your activity must extend from `ActionBarActivity`. It is defined in the Support Package which you have already added as I can see in your imports.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
                          implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your class needs to extends **ActionBarActivity**. 
Because of **ActionBarActivity** extends from **FragmentActivity**, you can use Fragments.